# position of html-link dosen't display correctly

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to display correctly links.
here is the problem, links are front of other links and can't see correctly..

[image]

and here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .btn3Link {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #4479BA;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}</style>
        <style>.btn3Link {padding: 10px 15px;background: #4479BA;color: #FFF;}.btn3Link:hover, .btn3Link:focus {background: #356094;border: solid 1px #2A4E77;text-decoration: none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a>
        <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> 
        <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give `display: inline-block`:

```
.btn3Link {display: inline-block;}
```

Inline elements cannot handle `padding` and `margin` on top and bottom, so they get overlapped or aligned to their baseline. Giving `display: inline-block` to them, gives them the power to be both inline as well as possess the block level attributes.

**Snippet**

```css
.btn3Link {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #4479BA;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a>
<a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> 
<a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a> <a class="btn3Link" href="dsds">test</a>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: thank you, but still links are "sticking" from up and down

Comment: @sarzin Add `margin: 5px 0;`